# How to call another api on error Spring WebFlux

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-webflux

I study WebFlux not too much, but I found a task that I cannot solve. If I have a timeout error in my current request I should call another api and if this API return ok - I should leave this method and continue executing my application. I wrote some code but I didn't found the solution.

```
        return WebClient.create(documentLocalUrlSettings.getBase())
        .post()
        .uri(documentLocalUrlSettings.getSend())
        .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(sendRequestDto))
        .headers(httpHeadersConsumer)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(SendAndStatusResponseDto.class)
        .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(10000))
        .retryWhen(errorCurrentAttempt -> errorCurrentAttempt
            .flatMap(tp -> {

                var status = WebClient.create("baseUrl")
                    .post()
                    .uri("callableServiceUrl")
                    .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(StatusRequestDto.class))
                    .retrieve();

                if (status != null && status.getResult().getResultCode() == 10001) {
                    return; 
                } else {
                    return Mono.<Object>error(new InternalRuntimeException(InternalExceptionCode.EX1001));  
                }
            })).block();
```

UPD: api call - sync

Answer (score 0):

You should read `retryWhen()` operator documentation since it's not doing what you are expecting. Instead of doing `retryWhen()` you should use operator `doOnError()` which takes function with argument of error emitted from `Mono` or `Flux` operation's where it is applied and return's value with new `Mono` or `Flux` emitting new behavior.

You should do something like this:

```
.timeout(Duration.ofMillis(10000))
.doOnError(error ->
    (error instanceof TimeoutException) 
        ? (/** call API here returning Mono **/) 
        : Mono.error(error)
).continueProcessingHere()
```

Also note that `.block()` method is not appropriate to be called when working with Webflux. `Webclient` you are using is already reactive so you don't need to block for result instead work with `Mono` or `Flux` you obtain from it and process result code's etc with `map()`, `flatMap()`, `onError()` etc operator's.

Comment: `doOnError` takes a consumer not a function. Meaning to returns void